# AMD Ryzen 5 4600H Ubuntu Graphics Drivers

Tags: amd-graphics

Hello i have a huawei matebook 14 with a ryzen 5 4600H,
[image: settings page]

I have ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS version , i have kernel version of 5.4.0-77-generic. I searched a lot but couldn't find any drivers for this iGPU,
it caused me a lot of problems. I had to reinstall ubuntu 3 times, i need help.
[image]
After downloading the radeon software 20.40 i get this error and i couldnt boot anymore. I had to get to recovery mode to amdgpu-uninstall. Then im back to zero.

Edit :
I downloaded 21.10 version and this was the result:
[image]

SOLVED:
i installed amdgpu 21.10 version again then typed this in terminal and rebooted.

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode -t string -s "glx" --create
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything after installation. Edit your question with more information. You should tell us the version and flavor or Ubuntu you are using. At a bare minimum you must provide clear unambiguous descriptions of the actual problems you are experiencing.  Copy paste any errors you are getting, verbatim and unredacted. Also tell us the steps taken to reproduce these errors.  You should also explain your research and tell us what you found and why it didn't work for you.  Without more detailed actionable information, there is not much we can do.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Can you also include the steps you are taking to download and install these drivers? Please don't upload pictures of your terminal. Instead, copy-paste and use three backticks before and after each code block to retain line breaks and formatting  Again, manually installing drivers shouldn't be necessary.  Your second screenshot looks like GPU artifacting. This usually indicates a hardware problem and not a software problem. Is this how your screen appears before you even attempt to manually install drivers?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, my screen is just fine when i dont install any drivers but when i install drivers manually (because ubuntu-drivers autoinstall doesnt see the drivers) i get this screen. Will do the three backticks thing.

Comment: So what makes you think you need to manually install drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I installed amdgpu 21.10 version again then typed this in terminal and rebooted.

```
xfconf-query -c xfwm4 -p /general/vblank_mode -t string -s "glx" --create
```